# ember - Setting controller property based on user/model attributes?

Tags: ember.js

I'm having a bit of trouble setting a property for my controller based off of a users attributes. Right now I have a simple set up where users can be admins of a group. I want to make it so if a user is an admin of a group, when they go to the groups/show page for that group, there is a form to create posts for that group, but this doesn't show up for regular members who are not admins.

Right now my controller looks like this:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

    loggedInUser: Ember.inject.service('user'),

  isAdmin: Ember.computed(function() {
        var that = this;

        //getting the current user and the list of groups they are
        //the admin of
        this.get('loggedInUser').get('currentUser.administrating')
            .then(function(groups) {

                //getting the id of the current group
                var groupID = that.get('group').get('id');

                    //looping over each group the user is an admin of
                    //and comparing the id to the current groups id
                    groups.forEach(function(group) {
                        if (group.get('id') == groupID) {
                            that.set('isAdmin', true);
                        } 
                    })
            });
    })


});
```

The problem is this only works the first time. For example if a user visits a groups/show page for a certain group, and is an admin for that group, it will show the form just fine. However upon further visits to other groups/show pages for other groups, it will show the form, even if that user is not an admin for that group. I've done some digging and it appears the problem is that the controller is a singleton, and persists when navigating to other pages. I've using `setupController` in the route to set the `isAdmin` to false, however that just sets the property to false every time. Is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: A computed function cannot (normally) return a promise. It also must have dependent properties to trigger its recalculation. Finally, it must return something--you're not returning anything at all. In this particular case, you might consider using an observer, which will be re-executed synchronously each time some property changes. By the way, your `forEach` can probably be rewritten using `includes`.

Answer (score 0):

As @torazaburo mentioned in the comment, a computed property must have a dependent key. Without that, it will not recompute when the user changes.

Also this part of your code

```
groups.forEach(function(group) {
  if (group.get('id') == groupID) {
    that.set('isAdmin', true);
  } 
})
```

should look something like this

```
groups.forEach(function(group) {
  if (group.get('id') === groupID) {
    return true;
  } 
});
return false;
```

If the user will not change while you are within the groups/show page, another approach would be to simply call a controller function from the setupcontroller and set isAdmin from there like this

```
//routes/groups/show.js
...
setupController(controller, model) {
this._super(controller, model);
controller.setAdmin();
...

//controllers/groups/show.js
...
isAdmin: false,
setAdmin() {
var that = this;

    //getting the current user and the list of groups they are
    //the admin of
    this.get('loggedInUser').get('currentUser.administrating')
        .then(function(groups) {

            //getting the id of the current group
            var groupID = that.get('group').get('id');

                //looping over each group the user is an admin of
                //and comparing the id to the current groups id
                groups.forEach(function(group) {
                    if (group.get('id') == groupID) {
                        that.set('isAdmin', true);
                        return;
                    } 
                });
                this.set('isAdmin', false);

        });
}
```